# Acessing "parent.child.MC"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a structure that is something like this - `holder.lineX.lineoverlay`

I want to access the movieclip "lineoverlay" on all children created

If I do something like this:

```
MovieClip(this.parent).lineX.lineoverlay.visible = false;
```

It works but I don't always know how many "line" movieclips I have, because they are created in runtime.

I tried this:

```
for (var i:uint = 1; i < MovieClip(parent).numChildren; i++) {
    MovieClip(this.parent).getChildAt(i).lineoverlay.visible = false;
}
```

But I keep getting an error because flash treats "lineoverlay" as an undefined property and not as movieclip.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getChildAt` returns a `DisplayObject`. `DisplayObject` is not a dynamic object (unlike Movieclip). So just cast it to movieclip in that case.

This should work:

```
for (var i:uint = 1; i < MovieClip(parent).numChildren; i++) {
    MovieClip(MovieClip(this.parent).getChildAt(i)).lineoverlay.visible = false;
}
```